# StatefulSets vs Deployments for stateless applications on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-statefulset

I find tons of articles and documentation describing the advantages of StatefulSets over Deployments for stateful applications on Kubernetes. What I haven't been able to figure out is the opposite: the disadvantages of StatefulSets when compared to Deployments, in particular for *stateless* applications.

Could someone please explain why not simply always use StatefulSets for both stateful and stateless applications?

Comment: We use statefulsets for our stateless application most because of the sequence naming suffix. It works nicely yet except for failure situation, you have to manually delete failure pod to recover.

Comment: Hi @a.l. can you please explain a bit more on your comment "you have to manually delete failure pod to recover." how is it different from deployment in your case ?

Comment: Hi @TajUddin, sometimes, we released a version which contains some error which makes the pod's state to be error, then we fixed it and release a new version, however, the error pod won't automatic be updated to the new good version, but has to be deleted first.
see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60164

Answer (score 4):

The most basic difference is that you would get ability to persist **pod level state** with statefulsets. Using volumeClaimTemplates, each replica will get a **unique PersistentVolumeClaim** with statefulset whereas all replicas would share the PersistentVolumeClaim with a deployment. This comes at a cost of **slow scale ups and scale downs** for statefulsets.

Deployments also have cool features related to "deployment" like rolling update with **maxSurge and maxUnavailable.**